# Replace multiple strings with multiple array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace multiple words in a string with multiple array. The string is "I have a wife, a car, and a home a boat."

```
 function CorrectString(text){
     CorrectionArr = array(
         'cat'=>array('wife'),
         'pen'=>array('boat', 'car')
     );
 }

 var text = "I have a wife, a car, and a home a boat.";
 text = CorrectString(text);
```

after replace

```
 var text = "I have a cat, a pen, and a home a pen.";
```

Comment: `'cat'=>array('wife'),` is not Javascript.

Comment: JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: this looks like php to me

Comment: Use string replace with a callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: i NOW only JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can use [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a callback.

Code:

```js
const text = 'I have a wife, a car, and a home a boat.';
const result = text.replace(/(wife)|(boat|car)/g, function (match, p1, p2) {
  if (p1) return 'cat';
  if (p2) return 'pen';
});
  
console.log(result);
```

Comment: i use only function for replace

Comment: please use function